# Brew Doctor not working

Tags: homebrew

```
> brew doctor
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

git
git-cvsserver
git-receive-pack
git-shell
git-upload-archive
git-upload-pack

Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Seem to be getting these warnings. How can I delete fuse.pc. Via 'rm'? Should I really need to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete anything.  This is just advice in case you are having other problems.

That said, if you don't know why or how this fuse package was installed, you could probably delete it.  But if something is using it, then probably not.  That's up to you.